# MySQL join problem

Tags: sql, mysql

Whats wrong with this SQL? It should return results but returns nothing

```
SELECT `pid` 
  FROM `products` 
  LEFT JOIN `prods_to_features` 
    ON (`ptf_pid` = `pid`) 
 WHERE (   `ptf_id` = '66' 
        OR `ptf_id` = '67'
       ) 
   AND (`ptf_id` = '76')
```

Is it not possible to have the 2nd where clause for the table that has been used in the left join?

Comment: When you're having problems like this, I recommend starting with the basics and adding pieces until it breaks.  For example, by taking out the whole where clause, it would have been obvious that the join works correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the WHERE clause makes no sense.

I'm going to guess that what you're trying to say is you want products that have a feature-76 AND have a feature 66-or-67. You will need two joins for that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.pid
FROM products
JOIN prods_to_features AS ptf1 ON ptf1.ptf_pid=products.pid
JOIN prods_to_features AS ptf2 ON ptf2.ptf_pid=products.pid
WHERE ptf1.ptf_id='76'
AND ptf2.ptf_id IN ('66', '67')
```

The DISTINCT is to ensure only one copy of a product is returned in the case where a product has both features 66 and 67.

Comment: my mistake, it actually does!

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at your WHERE clause.

You can't have a value be `(66 OR 67) AND 76` at the same time. Every row will return false for the expression, so no rows will be returned.

Answer (score 5):

The problem has nothing to do with your join.

You check for

```
(`ptf_id` = '66' OR `ptf_id` = '67') AND (`ptf_id` = '76')
```

which is the same as

```
   (`ptf_id` = '66' AND `ptf_id` = '76' )
OR (`ptf_id` = '67' AND `ptf_id` = '76')
```

which means `ptf_id = 66 = 76` or `ptf_id = 67 = 76` which is, well, unlikely.

Comment: not unlikely but impossibly for our generation of computers. with quantum computing it might be possible ;)

Comment: ...but I have pages worth of "proofs" that 1 = 2

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are asking it to return records from `prods_to_features` that have two different values for `ptf_id` (the `AND` in your Where clause).

I suspect you may mean `pid` for one or two of your `ptf_id` in the Where clause. It just depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your boolean logic is flawed.

WHERE (ptf_id = 66 or 67) and (ptf_id = 76)

this will never work.